# Access data on the stack

Tags: string, assembly, stack

I'm planning to write program in assembly that searches substring in string and writes words that contain substring. For example:

string: "adgfh asdsd zxc dbasdas"

substring: "as"

output: "asdsd dbasdas"

The idea is to use only one register (*DX*) and the stack to store data. I'm pushing string and substring into the stack. My main question is - is it possible to access the data under the top element in the stack without popping the data? I want to use *DX* to remember spaces between words and compare each letter in string to 1st letter in string, and if it's the same letter then increment the pointer in both string and substring to point at next letter in words and redo comparing...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access items on the stack because stack is just memory. However if you are in 16 bit mode, you can not use `DX` for that, you need `BX`, `SI`, `DI` or `BP`. For example:

```
mov bx, sp
mov bl, ss:[bx+10]
```

Note you need `ss` segment override for anything except `BP`. In 32 bit mode you can use `ESP` directly, such as:

```
mov dl, [esp+10]
```

PS: that's a fairly strange project for a first program ;)

Comment: thanks, for help!
got one more question... is there a way to get into 1st letter on on each string from stack without first checking their lenght and then adding to adress of ESP ? because using one registry might be a little hard to do this :D
i'm also thinking about pushing length of each string on top of the stack then adding value from top of the stack to the adress, but i'm not sure if this will work as intended :D ( because i need edx to remember spaces to the words that contain substring)

Comment: If you have more questions, please post them separately. That said, yes, storing the length and adjusting the address does sound reasonable.